# C++ Managing pointers to functions inside another class

Tags: c++

I'm trying to write a program that calls for a function stored inside a class whose implementation is defined by another object instance.
Let me clarify this better: I would like to create an object A and call for its functions (like an abstract object), but the body of this functions should be defined by either an instance of class B or class C.

I know abstract classes exist in C++ and that i could just call the derived objects, but my goal is to call for object A methods without caring (or knowing in advance) whether an instance of object B or C was previously created.

I tried to use pointers to functions, unfortunately with no results. My code was something like this

Class A:

```
class A {
public:
static void (*someFunction)();
};
```

Class B:

```
class B {
public:
B(){
    A::someFunction = someFunction;
}

private:
void someFunction(){
    std::cout << "some function" << std::endl;
}
};
```

Main code:

```
B b;
A::someFunction();
```

What am I doing wrong or could be done in a more simple and elegant way? Sorry for the poor explaination and thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do here? This sounds a bit like an XY problem--that you may just be trying to force a bad implementation onto your actual problem. Can you give us some more details?

Comment: What you describe reminds me somehow to the [PImpl idiom](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pimpl).

Comment: Are you familiar with `virtual` functions? Are you trying to virtualize a `static` function (like `A::someFunction` which is `static`) or a member function (like `B::someFunction` which is not `static`)?

Comment: This sounds like you just want both `B` and `C` to implement the same interface and be substitutable in a variable of type `A`. That is what an abstract class and class inheritance is for!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Polymorphism exists for just this type of situation, eg:

```cpp
class A {
public:
    virtual ~A() = default;
    virtual void someFunction() = 0;
};
```

```cpp
class B : public A {
public:
    void someFunction() override {
        std::cout << "some function" << std::endl;
    }
};
```

```cpp
class C : public A /* or B*/ {
public:
    void someFunction() override {
        std::cout << "some other function" << std::endl;
    }
};
```

```cpp
void doIt(A &a) {
    a.someFunction();
}

B b;
doIt(b);

C c;
doIt(c);
```

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/tkzwXy)

But, if that is not what you want, then consider having `A` use [`std::function`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) instead of a raw function pointer. Then `B` and `C` can assign whatever they want to `A::someFunction` using lambdas or [`std::bind()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind), eg:

A.h:

```cpp
#include <functional>

class A {
public:
    static std::function<void()> someFunction;
};
```

A.cpp:

```
#include "A.h"
std::function<void()> A::someFunction;
```

B.h:

```cpp
#include "A.h"

class B {
public:
    B(){
        A::someFunction = [this](){ someFunction(); };
        or:
        A::someFunction = std::bind(&B::someFunction, this);
    }

private:
    void someFunction(){
        std::cout << "some function" << std::endl;
    }
};
```

C.h:

```cpp
#include "A.h"

class C {
public:
    C(){
        A::someFunction = [this](){ someFunction(); };
        or:
        A::someFunction = std::bind(&C::someFunction, this);
    }

private:
    void someFunction(){
        std::cout << "some other function" << std::endl;
    }
};
```

```cpp
#include "A.h"
#include "B.h"
#include "C.h"

B b;
A::someFunction();

C c;
A::someFunction();
```

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/c0XvtJ)

Comment: Thanks! The second example is exactly what I was trying (badly) to accomplish. I also would like to thank everyone as well for their time.